# Excel - IF with 3 Outcomes

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

This question has been asked and answered, unfortunately when I adapt the answers to my situation all I get back is `#NAME?`. My need is a return out of "Positive", "Negative" or a no response, as follows

- “Positive” any number >0
- “Negative” any number <0 (negative number)
- No return for a zero

I have tried `=IF(A1=0;””;IF(A1<=0.01;”Negative”;“Positive”))` with using both semi-colons and commas.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Jon - thanks. The formula you gave worked but Excel insisted I insert ; and not , - somehow the my standard double quote in the formula I inserted above came out a bit weird. Your help is appreciated, not sure why it didn't work with commas though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a `#NAME?` error is due to the fancy quotation marks `“”` - change them to standard `"` and it will work.

Function inputs should also be separated by `,` not `;`, and your condition should test for less than zero:

```
=IF(A1=0,"",IF(A1<0,"Negative","Positive"))
```

Comment: Jon - thanks. The formula you gave worked but Excel insisted I insert ; and not , - somehow the my standard double quote in the formula I inserted above came out a bit weird. Your help is appreciated, not sure why it didn't work with commas though.

Comment: It's probably your language settings in Windows - see https://lockone.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/excel-now-using-semicolons-instead-of-commas-in-separating-formulas-fix-it-now/